# How do I use check() or Match.test() to validate Numbers?

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to validate in a method that is setup to create products in a basic inventory, but numbers representing currency ie, 99 or 99.95 run through check() and Match.test() throw an match fail or return false:

```
check(_data, {
    name: String,
    sku: String,
    retail: Number,
    cost: Number,
    qty: Number
});
```

The mismatch makes sense when the field value is being passed as a string directly from the form field. The problem is that if I parseInt() or parseFloat() the field value and I enter a string like 'asdf' then these two functions discard the value making it look like nothing was entered.

**How do I deal with Int and Float validation, including telling the user they have entered an invalid string instead of a number?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate decimal numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric)

Comment: Thanks, that is useful. The problem is that check() and Match.test() accept NaN as valid... so this means I have to then write extra logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I can find to handle this is to use [SimpleSchema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema)

```
var productSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        max: 64
    },
    sku: {
        type: String,
        max: 32
    },
    retail: {
        type: Number,
        decimal: true,
        min: 0
    },
    cost: {
        type: Number,
        decimal: true,
        min: 0
    },
    qty: {
        type: Number,
        min: 0
    }
});
```

Notice the `decimal: true` which handles floats. Combine simple schema with [Collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2) and you have automatic validation handling on database insert and update.

Answer (score 0):

A little work around I'm using in the client event to clean the data, but I consider a hack:

```
parseNumber = function(n) {
    if(!isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n)) {
        return parseFloat(n);
    } else {
        return n
    }
}
```

This at least lets check() and Match.test() work by passing through either a valid number or an invalid string. Otherwise they don't handle NaN elegantly.